# how can a c++ concept combine concepts?

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic, c++-concepts

I have inherited the following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept IsAwaiter = requires {
  typename T::await_ready;
  typename T::await_suspend;
  typename T::await_resume;
};

template <typename ...AWAITABLES>
concept IsAwaitables = typename std::conjunction<IsAwaiter<AWAITABLES>...>::type;
```

Building this with clang 10.0.0 results in the following error:

```
IsAwaiter.h:43:50: error: template argument for template type parameter must be a type
```

Perhaps just a simple syntax issue, but I've found it hard to find an example which shows how to create a concept based on a variadic template concept parameter.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `(IsAwaiter<AWAITABLES> && ...)`?

Comment: `std::conjunction` would break subsumption BTW.

Comment: regrettably, the compiler does not like this yet :(. Template meta-programming ~.

Comment: in line with your suggestion, i tried `concept IsAwaitables = typename std::conjunction(IsAwaiter<AWAITABLES> && ...)::type;` but the compiler responds with `/home/dja/sandbox/experimental/rubicon/player/api/player/detail/IsAwaiter.h:43:24: error: no viable constructor or deduction guide for deduction of template arguments of 'conjunction'`. I assume that is what you were suggesting..

Comment: Why are you using `conjunction`?

Comment: it was inherited.. I don't claim to know a great deal about meta-programming.

Comment: i suspect, in retrospect, that i misunderstood Jarod42's comment :(. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::conjunction` is for type traits. `std::conjunction<IsAwaiter<AWAITABLES>...>` is a type with a member `static bool value = (IsAwaiter<AWAITABLES>::value && ...)`, where each `IsAwaiter<AWAITABLES>` is itself expected to be a type trait with its own `static bool` member `value`. This is nonsensical when `IsAwaiter<AWAITABLES>` is a concept, because concepts are not type traits. They are "just" booleans. Use a fold expression.

```
template <typename... AWAITABLES>
concept IsAwaitables = (IsAwaiter<AWAITABLES> && ...);
```

That's it.

```
struct Dummy {
    using await_ready = Dummy;
    using await_suspend = Dummy;
    using await_resume = Dummy;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(IsAwaitables<>);
    static_assert(IsAwaitables<Dummy>);
    static_assert(IsAwaitables<Dummy, Dummy>);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your clear answer, HTNW. It seems like it is a fairly common use case so hopefully others find it useful, too.

Answer (score 7):

As [HTNW points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63799885/2069064), you want:

```cpp
template <typename ...T>
concept IsAwaitables =  (IsAwaiter<T> && ...);
```

But really, do you even need this concept at all? You can just use `IsAwaiter` directly. And it probably should just be named `Awaiter` - the typical convention for concepts is to name them as nouns rather than questions (e.g. `Range` vs `IsRange`).

If you're taking a parameter pack, you would want to use it anyway:

```cpp
template <Awaiter... T>
void f(T... awaiters);
```

and the same with the abbreviated function template syntax:

```cpp
void f(Awaiter auto... awaiters);
```

or if you have a fixed number of them, it especially doesn't make sense:

```cpp
template <Awaiter T, Awaiter U>
void f(T, U);
```

And even in other contexts where it doesn't neatly fit, it seems better to just manually use `Awaiter` with a fold-expression. So I question the need for the conjunction concept to begin with.

Comment: I still think there is some merrit to variadic concepts, but please change my perspective if there is a better alternative or if this goes against the *typical convention*. For example, when you have a templated `struct` as in `template<myconcept... Ts> struct t { ... };` and then some templated member functions that are dependent on the constraint of *myconcept*, as in `template<typename T> requires (std::convertible_to<Ts> or ...) auto f(T arg) { ... }`. Having to write the same `requires` clause over and over again instead of using a variadic `concept` feels rather bloaty.